# Unset is triggering too early and cancelling the earlier actions

Tags: php

I'm trying to create some code for a simple game - pick where the arrow will land, and the  computer "shoots" it and then displays either a "well done", or a "no it landed elsewhere" message, with an image of the arrow landed (once, refreshing should make them disappear).  Obviously using POST redirect, which is happening, but it doesn't seem to matter where I put the unset for the SESSION variables, it appears to unset too early, meaning that the messages don't display at all.

Searching online, I have been unable to see what's wrong (SESSION is carrying over, the redirect is working, but wherever the unset() goes it unsets and doesn't display at all), it's probably something simple, so would appreciate someone looking over my code (I've left in my various attempts commented out, so you can see the problem):

```
<?php
session_start();

function GuessArrowGame(){

    if (isset ($_POST['YourArrow'])){
        //Create array of possible answers
        $possibleScores = array ("miss","1","3","5","7","9");
        //print_r ($possibleScores);

        //Check output from dropdown
        //echo "POST is:";
        //print_r ($_POST);

        //Get _POST and make into a string
        $YourArrowLands = $_POST['YourArrow'];
        $SESSION['YourArrowLands'] = $YourArrowLands;
        //echo "Your arrow Lands \n";
        //print_r ($SESSION['YourArrowLands']);
        //echo "\n";
        //echo "\n";


        //Randomise array
        shuffle ($possibleScores);
        //print_r ($possibleScores);

        //Make variable from randomised array
        $ArrowLands = $possibleScores['0'];
        //echo "Arrow Lands: $ArrowLands \n";


        //Make Image from each arrow landing
        $ArrowLandsImage="0";

        if ($ArrowLands=="9"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Gold.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="7"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Red.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="5"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Blue.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="3"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Black.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="1"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="White.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="miss"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Miss.png";
        }
        echo "<p>Arrowlandsimage is ".$ArrowLandsImage."</p>\n";
        $_SESSION['ArrowImage'] = $ArrowLandsImage;
        echo $_SESSION['ArrowImage'];

        //check score against arrow
        if ($SESSION['YourArrowLands'] == $ArrowLands){
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Great job, you guessed right, you scored ".$ArrowLands.".\n";
        }else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Sorry, you guessed $YourArrowLands, but you scored ".$ArrowLands.".\n";
        }


        //Display image of arrow Landing
        //$SESSION['ArrowImage'] = $ArrowLandsImage;        


        header ("Location:Game1.php");
        return;
    }
};  


print_r ($_SESSION);
function flashMessages(){

    if (isset($_SESSION['ArrowImage'])) {
  echo $_SESSION['ArrowImage'];
  //unset($_SESSION['ArrowImage']);
}




    if ( isset ($_SESSION['message']) ) {
        echo("<p>".$_SESSION['message']."</p>\n");
        //unset($_SESSION['success']);
    }
    if ( isset ($_SESSION['ArrowImage']) ) {
echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION['ArrowImage'].'" title="Arrow Lands" alt="Arrow Lands" />';         
        echo "\n";
//      unset($_SESSION['ArrowImage']);
    }
}

        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Evolution Archers</title>
      <!--<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/EvoLogo.ico"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Style.css">
      <script src="JS/Script.js"></script>-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body id="top">
<!--<img  id="MenuShow" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('Menu');return false;" src="Images/Menu.png" alt="Menu Show">
<div id="Menu" class="more">
<img  id="MenuHide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('Menu');return false;" src="Images/MenuEnd.png" alt="Menu Hide">
</div>
      <nav class = "nav" id="nav">
            <a class="home" href='Index.html'>
              <img src="Images/EvoWebPageTopTransparent.png" alt="Home">
             </a>
                <a href='History.html'>History of the Club</a>
                <a href='Gallery.html'>Gallery</a>
                <a href='Upcoming.html'>Upcoming Events</a>
                <a href='Past.html'>Past Events</a>
                <a href='Beginners.html'>Beginners</a>
                <a href='LYG.html'>London Youth Games</a>
                <a href='Members.html'>Members Area</a>
                <a class="active" href='Useful.html'>Useful Stuff</a>
                <a href='Rules.html'>Rules and Etiquette</a>

        </nav>-->
                <div class=MainPage>

    <section>
        <h1>Can you hit the Gold?</h1>

        <!--Insert Code for clicky button here*/-->
        <form method="post">
        <p>
        <label for="GuessArrow">Where will your arrow land?</label>
        <select name="YourArrow" id="GuessArrow">
        <option value="9">9 - Gold</option>
        <option value="7">7 - Red</option>
        <option value="5">5 - Blue</option>
        <option value="3">3 - Black</option>
        <option value="1">1 - WhiteGold</option>
        <option value="miss">m - Miss</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>

        <?php
        GuessArrowGame();

        flashmessages();

    //$message = isset($_SESSION['message']) ? $_SESSION['message'] : false;
    //$imageShow = isset($_SESSION['ArrowImage']) ? $_SESSION['ArrowImage'] : false;

       /*if ( $message !== false )  {
        echo("<p>$message</p>\n");
 // unset($_SESSION['message']);
   }*/
        //Display image of arrow Landing
        /*if ($imageShow !== false){
            echo '<img src="'.$imageShow.'" title="Arrow Lands" alt="Arrow Lands" />';          
        echo "\n";
    //unset($_SESSION['ArrowImage']);
        }   */  

    /*  if (isset ($_SESSION['message'])){
    echo ("<p>".$_SESSION['message']."</p>\n");
    //echo ("printing check");
    unset($_SESSION['message']);

}*/

        ?>

<?php
//  echo($_SESSION['ArrowImage']);

    //unset($_SESSION['ArrowImage']);
    //unset($_SESSION['message']);
?>


        </section>
  <footer>
           <p>All content &copy; Evolution Archers 2004-2018 or individual members of Evolution Archers.</p>
           <p>Evolution Archers are not responsible for the content of other websites.</p>
           <p>Links to other websites do not indicate any association between Evolution Archers and other websites.</p>

      </footer>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You also have an invalid assignment in that function to `$SESSION['YourArrowLands']` ... forgot the underscore `$_SESSION`

Comment: Is there a question here? This is a whole ton of code, some of it commented out, and no hints as to where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is that you wish to clear out the message you set into $_SESSION after it redirects and displays it once. However that is not what its doing, and for this reason:

Your code sets up a redirect, but continues to execute the *whole page* (and the unsets). THEN it redirects back to itself. Which of course you see that the $_SESSION vars are empty.

To fix this in your code follow these steps...

1. Move `GuessArrowGame();` to *just before* you begin outputting `<!DOCTYPE html>...`.
2. Inside `function GuessArrowGame(){}` add `session_write_close();` before `header("Location:Game1.php");`
3. Inside `function GuessArrowGame(){}` add `exit;` right after `header("Location:Game1.php");`
4. Fix ALL `$SESSION` to `$_SESSION` you come across.
5. Put all your `unset` (or just do `$_SESSION=[];`) at the bottom of your code.

---

Your code after clearing comments and adding the above:

```
<?php
session_start();

function GuessArrowGame() {
    if (isset ($_POST['YourArrow'])) {
        $possibleScores = array ("miss","1","3","5","7","9");
        $YourArrowLands = $_POST['YourArrow'];
        $_SESSION['YourArrowLands'] = $YourArrowLands;
        shuffle ($possibleScores);
        $ArrowLands = $possibleScores['0'];
        $ArrowLandsImage="0";
        if ($ArrowLands=="9"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Gold.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="7"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Red.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="5"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Blue.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="3"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Black.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="1"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="White.png";
        }elseif($ArrowLands=="miss"){
            $ArrowLandsImage="Miss.png";
        }
        echo "<p>Arrowlandsimage is ".$ArrowLandsImage."</p>\n";
        $_SESSION['ArrowImage'] = $ArrowLandsImage;
        echo $_SESSION['ArrowImage'];
        if ($_SESSION['YourArrowLands'] == $ArrowLands){
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Great job, you guessed right, you scored ".$ArrowLands.".\n";
        }else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Sorry, you guessed $YourArrowLands, but you scored ".$ArrowLands.".\n";
        }

        session_write_close();
        header("Location: 998.php");
        exit;
        return;
    }
};
function flashMessages(){
    if (isset($_SESSION['ArrowImage'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['ArrowImage'];
    }
    if ( isset ($_SESSION['message']) ) {
        echo("<p>".$_SESSION['message']."</p>\n");
    }
    if ( isset ($_SESSION['ArrowImage']) ) {
        echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION['ArrowImage'].'" title="Arrow Lands" alt="Arrow Lands" />';         
        echo "\n";
    }
}

GuessArrowGame();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Evolution Archers</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body id="top">
    <div class=MainPage>
    <section>
        <h1>Can you hit the Gold?</h1>

        <form method="post">
        <p>
        <label for="GuessArrow">Where will your arrow land?</label>
        <select name="YourArrow" id="GuessArrow">
        <option value="9">9 - Gold</option>
        <option value="7">7 - Red</option>
        <option value="5">5 - Blue</option>
        <option value="3">3 - Black</option>
        <option value="1">1 - WhiteGold</option>
        <option value="miss">m - Miss</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>

        <?php flashmessages(); ?>

        </section>
    <footer>
           <p>All content &copy; Evolution Archers 2004-2018 or individual members of Evolution Archers.</p>
           <p>Evolution Archers are not responsible for the content of other websites.</p>
           <p>Links to other websites do not indicate any association between Evolution Archers and other websites.</p>
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    unset($_SESSION['ArrowImage']);
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
?>
```

Comment: I have a temporary *paste* of that above code working here: http://bytejunkies.com/test/998.php

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it.  

So to check my understanding -   
- $SESSION, wasn't helping, but wasn't the cause    
- GuessArrowGame() was used too far down the page    
- session_write-close stops any further code from working on this load?    
- exit; also stops code executing further down?
- Why does the unset need to be right at the bottom (I've just done a course, and the various if isset bits are based on that including the unset, so I'm no sure why they weren't working this time)     

Thanks

Comment: `session_write_close()` ensures any changes you made to the `$_SESSION` variable get saved before the php exits. Sometimes not needed, but I always use it to be sure. `exit();` halts the php script, because you are doing a header redirect, so theres no reason to continue at that point (in your example, that is). And I put the `unset` on the bottom, because it was the clearest example. It COULD go inside `flashMessages(){ }` at the bottom of that function too.

Comment: Thanks.   That's much clearer.  how does `exit();` differ from `return;`?  Sorry, still learning, not much better than a total noob.

Comment: `return;` is for inside a function or method to end the execution of just that function or method (with optional parameters passed out, like `return array('stuff'=>true);`. It can be used at the global level to 'return the php to what included it'... but its not as commonly used that way. `exit();` used anywhere, will kill the execution of the entire php script run. Use `exit();` to just stop everything and drop it back to the user. `die();` is an alias to exit... good for making the code readable that you want it to DIE!!!!! ...